# R: transforming "short form" data to "long form" data without for loops?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have an R dataframe like this:

```
  Subject Session  Property.A Property.B Property.C
1     100       1 -1.22527548 -0.9193751 -1.7501693
2     100      10  2.30627980  1.8940830 -0.8443976
3     100       2  2.33243332 -0.5860868 -4.2074489
4     100       3  0.38130810 -0.7336206  4.8016230
5     100       4  1.44685875  0.5066249  2.0138624
6     100       5  0.08907721 -0.3715202  1.4983700
```

I have heard this style of data frame referred to as "short form" or "wide form". Now suppose I want to make it look like this, which I have heard called "long form":

```
  Subject Session  Property    Value
1     100       1         A   -1.2252754
2     100       1         B   -0.9193751
3     100       1         C   -1.7501693
4     100       2         A    2.3324333
5     100       2         B   -0.5860868
6     100       2         C   -4.2074489
```

That is, I have N columns that I want to reduce to just two "name/value" columns, with any other columns in the dataframe extended with repeated values as necessary.

Obviously I could perform this conversion with a bunch of for loops, but that seems really ugly, and it would be a pain to maintain if/when I add more property columns.

Is there a way to do this in R with just a few lines of code? Some magic combination of functions I haven't discovered yet?

Comment: Update: nowadays, I've gotten wise, and I use `plyr` for all my data-reshaping needs!

Comment: What is the way to do that in plyr?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `melt` function in package `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = c("Subject", "Session"))
```

If you need to clean up the column names and/or values for the variable column:

```
#change "variable" to "Property"
names(dat.m)[3] <- "Property"
#Drop "Property." from the column values
dat.m$Property <- gsub("Property\\.", "", dat.m$Property)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. I'm checking out the reshape package docs now, what a great concept. Don't know how I EVER would have found it by searching, though, with such purely metaphorical, non-descriptive terminology as "melt", "molten", and "cast". This seems like such a common thing to want to do, how can it not be a part of basic R functionality?

Comment: the `reshape` function in stats comes with base R and provides seemingly equivalent functionality to melt and cast, though I've never tried to learn it as the syntax of `melt` and `cast` are pretty easy to pick up on. As for searching on things, I guess you do have a bit of a point - luckily there's SO!

Comment: Or use `reshape2` which can be quite a bit faster

Answer (score 4):

I like using `plyr` functions, but the `reshape` function from base is quite powerful, as illustrated by the solution below.

```
# create a dummy data frame
dat = data.frame(
  subject = rep(100, 5),
  session = sample(5, 10, replace = T),
  property.a = rnorm(5),
  property.b = rnorm(5),
  property.c = rnorm(5)
)

# convert wide to long, varying columns are 3:5, separator is "."
dat.long = reshape(dat, direction = 'long', varying = 3:5, sep = ".")
```

Comment: +1 for this. I spent 10 minutes trying to make this work to post in my answer as an alternative, but kept getting bogged down along the way.

Answer (score 2):

reshape package for this is great for this but... a bunch of loops is not the alternative.

perhaps this example is instructive...

```
longDF <- lapply( 3:4, function(x) cbind(wideDF[1:2], p = names(wideDF)[x], wideDF[x]) )
longDF <- rbind( longDF )
```

or this one

```
longDF <- cbind( rep(wideDF[1], 3), rep(wideDF[2], 3), c(wideDF[3], wideDF[4], wideDF[5]) )
```